# event based model client and ChannelFactory<T>

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, client

Hallo again my question regards to event based model client development in WCF service client infrastructure. what I would lice to know is that, instead of using ClientBase is it possible to manually implement this patten with ChannelFactory so for example I could write GetDataAsync for client access and still using ChannelFactory and implementing serverside async calls here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will depend on whether you control the service contract or not. If you can define the service contract then you add the appropriate begin/end methods that return/use the IAsyncResult as [shown in the code in this blog post.](http://agilenet.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/wcf-making-multiple-async-calls-with-the-channelfactory/)

If you can't change the service contract then you must create an async version of the service contract manually and feed that to the ChannelFactory. The ChannelFactory itself does not provide an async mode of service operation invocation. Your code will end up looking something like the [code in this MSDN sample.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885132.aspx)

Comment: yes I control both client and server so I can directly add reference to my contracts dll. And the link u gave to me is not what exactly I want to know. What I want to see is using channel factory and still implementing based on event based pattern on clientside

Comment: Look at the MSDN sample link in the answer, it shows pretty clearly how to call the service asynchronously. You just need to determine where your version of the AddCallback method will be implemented in you application.

Comment: I understand MSDN sample but it is traditional async pattern with BeginXXX / EndXXX and there is no event based model approach there so back to my original question. I wanted to have event based model implemented on the client side while WCF service uses some async operations as well

Comment: Looks like it is not possible to to what I thought would be best.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885132.aspx

after reading this it makes me think that event based pattern is not the way to work with Channel Factory

Comment: My thinking was that within the event structure that you create for your app, the code would be calling the WCF service asynchronously. The callback methods would raise the appropriate events for handling the service response. WCF itself doesn't directly provide an event-driven programming model.

Comment: that is point to create custom even infrastructure and that's what I am going to implement.